# how can i make jquery tree with two level only?

Tags: jquery, treeview

i am beginer in jquery and i don't have experince in jquery but i need to use 
tree with two level , since when i click on ?one link new links appear down of it , 
just like hotmail inbox idea ! can some one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to check out this jQuery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use jquery to build the tree. You can simlpy build the tree by using html and some + image sybol. you can control in the code to what leve you want to show the tree.
Normally we uses recursive loops to build the tree. Whenever there is leaf node we add dot image and whenever there are children under it we can add + image symbol.